# How to automatically create tables with different names, but same shape?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

If I define a struct that implements `Queryable` and `Insertable` and use the `table!` macro to create a representation of a table, Diesel will automatically assume that I am writing to a specific table named after an argument passed to `table!`. How can I structure my code to dynamically name tables while reusing the same schema?

In other words, I would like to tell Diesel what the table name is at the `insert_into` stage, but the struct and its fields will be known at compile time. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this feels like it's against the purpose of Diesel. Diesel works by creating types that represent your table and columns. Types only exist at compile time. You are attempting to create such at runtime.

Comment: @Shepmaster gotcha. Sounds like what I need is SQLx or similar, where I write SQL queries myself.

Comment: If you want to dynamically create tables with the same schema, it sounds like you actually want a single table with an additional column. Keep data out of table names (or mostly any kind of name, with a few exceptions).

Comment: My use case is for multiple timeseries with the same record type, but different sources indicated by their names. I thought about what you are proposing, but that would create a database with just one, enormous table. Not sure if that's good design?

Comment: It's normally fine to have a large table in a database. If queries are slow you can just use a index on the "additional column". For really large tables, table partitions may be interesting.
From diesel's side there is the currently unreleased diesel-dynamic-schema (https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel-dynamic-schema) to support usecases where the schema is not statically known at compile time.

Comment: I think I found a solution for efficient chunking. Timescaledb is a postgres extension, which chunks the table along specified dimensions in a transparent way. To the outside world, the table acts just like a regular table, but behind the scenes, the extension breaks it into smaller pieces. Sounds like this would solve the problem - I would still be able to use diesel to interact with the db without having to deal with performance issues of a huge table.